# How to shape dataset for training in Keras?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, lstm

I am trying to train an LSTM in Keras on microgrid dataset from this [site](http://traces.cs.umass.edu/index.php/Smart/Smart). There are 443 files each for one home containing electric consumption data for each minute for 24 hours (1440 rows).

At first, I choose only one file and created a dataset by taking n samples at each step and making `(n+1)th` value the label.

Now, I want to combine all data-files and train.

How can I create train and test datasets?